# update table1 after insert record in table2

Tags: mysql

I need to update the stock in the product table when I insert records in the sales table.

These are my tables:

Table products:

```
idprod int primary key  
name varchar (20)  
description varchar (100)  
int stock
```

Sales table:

```
idsale int primary key  
idprod int foreign key  
quantity int
```

and these are my stored procedures:

```
create procedure update_stock()  
begin  
update products  
inner join sales on products.idprod = sales.idprod  
set products.stock = products.stock-sales.quantity;  
end

create procedure add_sale(in s_id int, in p_id int, in qua int)  
begin  
insert into sales values(s_id, p_id, qua);  
call update_stock ();  
end
```

First I fill the table products with some data, then I call the procedure add_sale. I have no problems with the first record in the sales table, but when I add more records, the stock of all products in the products table is updated instead of just one.

Comment: you can use trigger for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your question ,you have two stored procedure but in update_stock() stored procedure you have not defined the WHERE clause so your stored procedure should be like this

```
 create procedure update_stock(  
    @id int
    )
    begin  
    update products  p,
     sales s  
    set products.stock = products.stock-s.quantity WHERE p.idprod = s.idprod and WHERE p.idprod=@idvalue ;  
    end
```

Comment: this code Works: update products p, sales s set p.stock=p.stock-5 where p.idprod=s.idprod and s.idprod=1; but when i implement it on a stored procedure doesn't work correctly

Comment: try this Stored procedure

Comment: I made some changes to the procedure stored in this line: SET p.stock = p.stock-qua WHERE p.idprod = s.idprod and s.idprod = id; and in this line: create procedure update_stock(in id int, in qua int)

Now everything works perfectly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The inserted product id is missing in your update clause. You have to pass it through your `update_stock()` call.

Modify `update_stock` procedure to take product id and quantity as input like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_stock(IN pid INT, IN qua INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE products  
  SET stock = stock - qua
  WHERE idprod = pid; 
END
```

By passing `qua` to the procedure we can prevent additional join to the other table.

Then call `update_stock` method within `add_sale` by passing `pid` and `qua` like below.

```
call update_stock (p_id, qua);
```

Comment: I tried and works, but stock decreases at unusual way.